# Do we have any source to setup AppSync Simulator for HTTP Datasource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I am a DevOps engineer with little knowledge of typescript.

Our dev team succeed in setting up the appsync simulator for DynamoDB & OpenSearch Datasource. I started tweaking it to add HTTP Datasource support, and I managed the simulator to hit the HTTP endpoint (VTL resolvers/functions) upon running query on the `http://localhost:8080/graphiql/` and get a response in the backend but somehow it is not showing on the GraphQL UI with an error

> Unable to convert   \n to class com.amazonaws.deepish. transform.model.lambda.LambdaVersionedConfig.

The UI interface is hosted by the docker.
I found that this error is coming from `amplify-appsync-simulator` library only.
Please share an example to setup HTTP datasource enabled appsync simulator using same `amplify-appsync-simulator` library.

[image]

Is there any other way to create a simulator that supports HTTP datasource? I am ok even if other datasources like database/opensearch are not supported.